# attach an image from attachment id to woocommerce product category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I know attachment id of an image which was uploaded through WP admin. Lets say ID is 130. If i write

```
echo wp_get_attachment_image(130);
```

i can see the image in browser. Now i create a product category in woo-commerce. Lets say it's term id is 33. I have not uploaded any image to this category from browser yet. From PHP i want to attach image with attachment id 130 to this product category. How to achieve that?

For example if i want to edit the name of the category i can write

```
wp_update_term(33, $taxonomy, array('name' => 'New name'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to update the `thumbnail_id`, like you are updating the `name`.

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_term Allowed args have no such option